How to start guacamole websocket tunnel?
The guacamole docs gives the simplest tunnel possible:
package org.apache.guacamole.net.example;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleException;
import org.apache.guacamole.net.GuacamoleSocket;
import org.apache.guacamole.net.GuacamoleTunnel;
import org.apache.guacamole.net.InetGuacamoleSocket;
import org.apache.guacamole.net.SimpleGuacamoleTunnel;
import org.apache.guacamole.protocol.ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket;
import org.apache.guacamole.protocol.GuacamoleConfiguration;
import org.apache.guacamole.servlet.GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet;

public class TutorialGuacamoleTunnelServlet
    extends GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet {

    @Override
    protected GuacamoleTunnel doConnect(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws GuacamoleException {

        // Create our configuration
        GuacamoleConfiguration config = new GuacamoleConfiguration();
        config.setProtocol("vnc");
        config.setParameter("hostname", "localhost");
        config.setParameter("port", "5901");
        config.setParameter("password", "potato");

        // Connect to guacd - everything is hard-coded here.
        GuacamoleSocket socket = new ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket(
                new InetGuacamoleSocket("localhost", 4822),
                config
        );

        // Return a new tunnel which uses the connected socket
        return new SimpleGuacamoleTunnel(socket);;

    }

}

That starts an HTTP tunnel. However i want to use websocket tunnel due to it's low latency.
My question is how to implement websocket tunnel in java side?
Or does "GuacamoleHTTPTunnelServlet" class already deal with websocket upgrading if i call WebsocketTunnel function in javascript code?
I tried to use Guacamole.WebsocketTunnel function, however it needs auth token at the end of url:
let tunnel = new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel(`/websocket-tunnel?token=${token}`);

I couldn't find a way to get the token as well. I'm open to all ideas.

Worth checking https://github.com/hoophq/hoop as a better alternative

Guacamole is suitable for environments needing web-based access to remote desktops or servers. Hoop is different, as far as i understand it's ssh and kubernetes gateway. How can i do the same thing with it? It looks impossible.
